# SQL - Unpivot result of one column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, unpivot

on `Oracle 10g`,  say i have this following column :

```
col
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[1,98]([1,81]([6,100828],[6,101260]),[1,81]([6,100529],[6,101259]),[1,81]([6,101709],[6,100474]))
```

and i want to display this result:

```
col
------
100828
101260
100529
101259
101709
100474
```

Is it possible to display this result with an SQL query?

Actually what i tried :

```
SELECT SUBSTR(col, INSTR(col, ',', 1, 3) + 1, 6) exp_1,
       SUBSTR(col, INSTR(col, ',', 1, 5) + 1, 6) exp_2,
       SUBSTR(col, INSTR(col, ',', 1, 8) + 1, 6) exp_3,
       SUBSTR(col, INSTR(col, ',', 1, 10) + 1, 6) exp_4,
       SUBSTR(col, INSTR(col, ',', 1, 13) + 1, 6) exp_5,
       SUBSTR(col, INSTR(col, ',', 1, 15) + 1, 6) exp_6
  FROM (SELECT '[1,98]([1,81]([6,100828],[6,101260]),[1,81]([6,100529],[6,101259]),[1,81]([6,101709],[6,100474]))' col
          FROM dual) ; 

EXP_1  EXP_2  EXP_3  EXP_4  EXP_5  EXP_6
------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
100828 101260 100529 101259 101709 100474
```

however, the number of returned exp_% could be variable and are always pair, which means one another row could return 8 exp_% :

```
SUBSTR(col, INSTR(col, ',', 1, 18) + 1, 6) exp_7 ,
SUBSTR(col, INSTR(col, ',', 1, 20) + 1, 6) exp_8
```

Suggestions when number of exp_% is fix are more than welcome too!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume your table is named 'foo' with a column name of 'col':

```
with q as (
    select ','||regexp_replace(
        regexp_replace(
            regexp_replace(
                regexp_replace(col, '[[0-9,]*]\(', ''), 
                    '\[[0-9],', ''), 
                '[])]', ','), 
        ',,+', 
        ',') a from foo
) 
select data 
  from (select substr(a, instr(a, ',', 1, rownum) + 1, 6) data 
          from q,
               (select 1 from q connect by level < length(regexp_replace(a, '[0-9]', '')))
       )
;
```

Here's the explanation. This gets complex quickly and probably wouldn't scale very well so buyer beware.

First I want to get rid of the '[1,98](' fields.

```
  1  with q as (
  2  select
  3          regexp_replace(col, '[[0-9,]*]\(', '')
  4  from foo
  5  )
  6* select * from q

REGEXP_REPLACE(COL,'[[0-9,]*]\(','')
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[6,100828],[6,101260])[6,100529],[6,101259])[6,101709],[6,100474]))
```

Next I want to get rid of the '[n,' portion of the fields.

```
  1  with q as (
  2  select
  3      regexp_replace(
  4          regexp_replace(col, '[[0-9,]*]\(', ''),
  5          '\[[0-9],', ''
  6      ) a from foo
  7  )
  8* select * from q

A
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
100828],101260])100529],101259])101709],100474]))
```

Now get rid of all ']' and ')'

```
  1  with q as (
  2  select
  3      regexp_replace(
  4      regexp_replace(
  5          regexp_replace(col, '[[0-9,]*]\(', ''),
  6          '\[[0-9],', ''),
  7          '[])]', ',')
  8       a from foo
  9  )
 10* select * from q

A
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
100828,,101260,,100529,,101259,,101709,,100474,,,
```

Get rid of duplicate commas and prepend with a comma.

```
  1  with q as (
  2  select ','||regexp_replace(
  3      regexp_replace(
  4      regexp_replace(
  5          regexp_replace(col, '[[0-9,]*]\(', ''),
  6          '\[[0-9],', ''),
  7          '[])]', ','),
  8      ',,+',
  9      ',') a from foo
 10  )
 11* select * from q

A
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
,100828,101260,100529,101259,101709,100474,
```

Figure out how many fields their are and create a row for each.

```
  1  with q as (
  2  select ','||regexp_replace(
  3      regexp_replace(
  4      regexp_replace(
  5          regexp_replace(col, '[[0-9,]*]\(', ''),
  6          '\[[0-9],', ''),
  7          '[])]', ','),
  8      ',,+',
  9      ',') a from foo
 10  )
 11* select 1 from q connect by level < length(regexp_replace(a, '[0-9]', ''))

     1
----------
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
```

Do a cartesian join with q (note this won't work if there's more than one row in your table.) and a substring to get your final answer.

```
  1  with q as (
  2  select ','||regexp_replace(
  3      regexp_replace(
  4      regexp_replace(
  5          regexp_replace(col, '[[0-9,]*]\(', ''),
  6          '\[[0-9],', ''),
  7          '[])]', ','),
  8      ',,+',
  9      ',') a from foo
 10  )
 11  select data
 12    from (select substr(a, instr(a, ',', 1, rownum) + 1, 6) data
 13        from q,
 14         (select 1 from q connect by level < length(regexp_replace(a, '[0-9]', '')))
 15*        )

DATA
------
100828
101260
100529
101259
101709
100474


6 rows selected.
```

Comment: Note this gets potentially a lot easier in 11g with pivot/unpivot

Comment: Thank you Richard! this is quite impressive, im still a bit lost and would like to ask you its its also possible to get the result per pair, means two per row, in our example 100828,101260 and second row 100529,101259 ect...

Comment: It should be possible.  If I get time, I'll see if I can come up with how.

Comment: Thanks, i added concatenation || with substr(a, instr(a, ',', 1, rownum) + 8, 6) and a row_number() and in the where clause to get odd numbers only WHERE MOD(rn, 2) <> 0, it works fine now, thanks again for you r help!